# cassandra 2.0.7 cql SELECT Secific Value from map

Tags: select, dictionary, cql3, cassandra-2.0

ALTER TABLE users ADD todo map;

UPDATE users  SET todo =  { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3' ,.... }  WHERE user_id = 'frodo';

now ,i want to run the follow cql ,but failed ,is here any other method ?

SELECT  user_id, todo['1'] FROM users WHERE user_id = 'frodo';

ps:

the length my map can change. for example :  { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3' }  or  { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3', '4':'4444'} or { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3', '4':'4444' ...}

Comment: See the following 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024839/select-secific-value-from-map

I think it would solve your problem.

Comment: my situation is different from your url recommended.
the length my map can change. for example :  { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3' }  or  { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3', '4':'4444'} or { '1':'1111', '2':'2222', '3':'3', '4':'4444' ...}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a map collection, you'll have the limitation that you can only select the collection as a whole ([docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html)).

I think you could use the suggestion from the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061523/9965), even if the length of your map changes. If you store those key/value pairs for each `user_id` in separate fields, and make your primary key based on `user_id` and `todo_k`, you'll have access to them in the select query.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id text,
  todo_k text,
  todo_v text,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, todo_k)
);

-----------------------------
| user_id | todo_k | todo_v |
-----------------------------
| frodo   | 1      | 1111   |
| frodo   | 2      | 2222   |
| sam     | 1      | 11     |
| sam     | 2      | 22     |
| sam     | 3      | 33     |
-----------------------------
```

Then you can do queries like:

```
select user_id,todo_k,todo_v from users where user_id = 'frodo';
select user_id,todo_k,todo_v from users where user_id = 'sam' and todo_k = 2;
```